# Spherical coordinates changing when the radius changes

Tags: polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

Assume i know the radius and some coordinates of a sphere. let say the initial radius is 20. When i change the radius of the sphere say 80, is there an equation to calculate the new coordinates using the initial coordinates ?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have the coordinates of the center as $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, and the coordinates of some point as $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, on the sphere.

If we *dilate* the sphere, by some positive constant $k>0$, this can correspond to a  growth or shrink, depending on whether $k>1$ , by the way, then the center remains stationary, while the distances from the center change.

Let's rewrite that coordinate on the sphere as *distances* (they aren't actual distances, just relative position vectors.)

We have $(x_1,y_1,z_1)=(x_0+(x_1-x_0),y_0+(y_1-y_0),z_0+(z_1-z_0))$

When we scale by $r$, the *distances* between the center and the point are scaled by $r$ too.

Therefore, we have $\boxed{(x_1,y_1,z_1) \mapsto (x_0+k(x_1-x_0),y_0+k(y_1-y_0),z_0+k(z_1-z_0))}$.

---

An example: We have a sphere with center $(2,2,3)$ and a point on it $(4,5,7)$. The sphere changes from radius $\sqrt{29}$ to $3\sqrt{29}$. This means our radius was tripled, or $k=3$.

Therefore, the differences in each coordinate triple. So the new point is $(8,11,15)$.